# Get Shared Folders in Outlook where recipients are not known

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to get all shared folders in Outlook using C#.

I know of the method [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getshareddefaultfolder-method-outlook) but it requires a recipient be specified.

I would like to know how to get all shared folders when I don't know about recipients.

Comment: Well, if you don't know the recipient address, how can you open the mailbox?

Comment: It's for calendar folder and aims to attach event handler within the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

Call `Namespace.CreateRecipient` passing the recipient name or address. Use the returned `Recipient` object to call `Namespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the name of the recipient; it can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP e-mail address of the recipient. In that case you will be able to create a recipient object and get the shared folder as the following sample code shows:

```
 Sub ResolveName() 
   Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
   Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 

   Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
   Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
   myRecipient.Resolve 
   If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
     Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
   End If 
 End Sub 

 Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
   Dim CalendarFolder As Folder 
   Set CalendarFolder = _
     myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder _ 
     (myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
   CalendarFolder.Display 
 End Sub
```